# Django listening to an specific port and redirect to a view

Tags: django, port

I have a django application, It has a list of urls and views. right now it listens to port 8000 I want to add one more url to current application but it listens to port 8001 is it even possible?If yes please give me some keywords or examples
thanks

Comment: Both are different or same project

Comment: @sakthiPanneerselvam Hi, They are in same project.